# new pc build-- CDROM not booting

Tags: motherboard, bios

I've just finished a new PC build using a Gigabyte GA-970A-UD3 AM3+ motherboard and SATA DVDROM and HDD.

I've set up the bios to use the following boot order:

CDROM
HDD

I know that the CDROM drive is connected properly and working, since I can boot from it *if* the HDD is disconnected. But when the hard drive is connected, the HDD boots first. It's driving me nuts, the boot order is set properly-- why would it not boot from the CDROM?

Other points:

1. the boot preferences / order are being saved in the BIOS so I don't
   think it's anything obvious like the battery being dead or settings
   are not saving.
2. Hitting F12 on reboot and manually selecting the CDROM as first boot
   still results in HDD boot
3. I've double checked that the CDROM is plugged into SATA port 0, and
   the HDD is in port 1, since some posts have said that the SATA boot
   order will follow the port number by default
4. Even after setting boot order as CDROM DISABLED DISABLED (so nothing should be booting except CDROM) the same issue occurs and HDD boots.

Comment: I've now set all three items in the boot order to CDROM and it STILL boots from the HDD. Also, the USB keyboard is recognized if I want to go into the BIOS setup, but once it displays the Windows "safe boot" options or GRUB loader screen (with a different HDD using dual boot Windows/Linux) the keyboard is not recognized. Any ideas?

Comment: I'll continue this conversation with myself-- the keyboard issue was resolved by setting "legacy USB support" to true in the bios.

Comment: not an actual solution to your problem, but a workaround: have you tried booting from a usb-stick? if you have a liveCD-image there are tools like unetbootin that can copy them to a stick.

Comment: @WalterMaier-Murdnelch-- actually, yes, I have. It doesn't seem to work either. I would like to boot to a Win7 install disk so I can reinstall Windows on a partition that is set up for it. But I simply cannot get the CDROM to boot! Thanks.

Comment: There is boot order, then there is boot priority, check you bios settings again, try using another port on the motherboard for the cdrom if it is available.

Comment: @Moab-- in this BIOS there's "Hard Disk Boot Priority" and "First Boot Device", "Second Boot Device" etc. Under the HD Boot Priority menu there's only the HD I've installed, and "Bootable Add in Card", which I've made first on the list in the hopes it would mean the CDROM. No luck. I've also tried other SATA ports on the mobo for the CDROM, with same results.

Comment: 0. Is the CD-DVD youre trying to boot booting on other computers? 1. Look if you got an option called `boot other devices` and set it to `disabled`;

Comment: I am having nearly the exact same problem. Did you ever figure this out?